# Lower bound of an infinite product

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, infinite-product, upper-lower-bounds

Let $p\in (0,1)$. How can I prove that there exists $c>0$ such that

$$\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-(1-p)^2\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\bigg)^{2i}}{\Bigg(1+(1-p)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\bigg)^{i}\Bigg)^2}\geq c.$$
Is it possible to extimate this constant $c$?

I think that we can bound from below the previous product with

$$\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-(1-p)^2\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\bigg)^{2i}}{1+(1-p)^2\bigg(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\bigg)^{2i}}.$$
But after how can I conclude?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Now it works. How good an estimate do you need? Of course better estimates require more work.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I modified the question again and I wrote my original problem. Do you think that in this case it is possible to find this constant $c$? I just need a$c>0$, I don't need a good estimate. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let $a = 1-p$ and $q = 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. The most important fact is that $\lvert q\rvert < 1$ (also, that none of the factors is $0$). That $a > 0$ (even $0 < a < 1$) and $q > 0$ is less important, but it makes things easier and can help in obtaining sharper bounds. Now let $P_1 = \prod_{i = 0}^{\infty}(1 + aq^i)$ and $P_2 = \prod_{i = 0}^{\infty} (1 + a^2q^{2i})$. You want a lower bound for $P_2/P_1^2$. You can get one from a lower bound $c_2$ for $P_2$ and an upper bound $c_1$ for $P_1$, for we then have $P_2/P_1^2 \geqslant c_2/c_1^2$. Now $P_2 \geqslant 1$ is trivial.

Comment: For an upper bound of $P_1$, use $1 + x \leqslant e^x$, thus $$P_1 \leqslant \exp \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} aq^i = \exp \frac{a}{1-q}\,.$$

Comment: Sorry Daniel! I made a mistake when I wrote the numerator in the text . There is a - and not a +. Thank you anyway for your answer and for your time.

Comment: $1 - x \geqslant e^{-2x}$ for $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ then gives a positive lower bound.

Comment: I think I understood. I will try to do all the computations. Thank you very much!